# Android:How to apply theme to android application

Tags: android

We have a requirement that the user has to select a theme out of 5 themes and we need to set the selected theme for all the activities of our application. Any idea on this.

Appreciate your time on this.

Thanks

Comment: More closely define what you mean by theme. Does this mean theme in the sense of full screen, no title bar, etc.(like when making layouts in Eclipse), or does this more mean something like colour scheme?

Comment: we have 5 background images based on the user selection we need to apply the selected background image to all the activities.

Answer (score 0):

create a class say theme manager declare static functions for every compont which returns int

say

```
public static int getTop()
{

return R.Drawable.top1;
}
```

on the activity just call

```
   top.setBackGroundResource(thememanager.getTop());
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach this is as follows:

**Step 1:**

Create a public dummy variable (to be used in all your activities), and an array for your themes like so;

```
public Integer background;
private Integer[] mImageIds = {
    R.drawable.theme1,
    R.drawable.theme2,
    R.drawable.theme3,
    R.drawable.theme4,
    R.drawable.theme5,
};
```

**Step 2:**

Have your method of choosing the background (a list, button, whatever) select an element of the array(0-4) and assign it to the background variable;

```
position = 1; % ranging from 0-4
background = mImageIds[position];
```

**Step 3:**

When you load each activity, set the background to be your background variable. (The way I'm about to show how to do this is kind of cheating, it's applying it to be the content of an image view which spans the screen).

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(R.id.background-box);
iv.setImageResource(background);
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

Another way you could achieve the final step is setting the background of an empty text view to be your image like so;

```
TextView tv = new TextView(R.id.background-textbox);
tv.setBackgroundResource(background);
```

Comment: You never got back to me, did this work for you? If so, please select answer.